# anaconda and point cloud library

Tags: python, point-cloud-library

Can you tell me how can I configure point cloud library to be used with anaconda, I have never used point cloud before. I have installed `pcl1.6.0` all in one installer, `openNI` and `PrimeSense`. But even after this when I run my python code in anaconda it gives me the error:

> ImportError: No module named pcl

Do I need to copy my `pcl1.6.0` folder in the site-package folder if anaconda?

the code is here:

```
import pcl 
p = pcl.PointCloud()
p.from_file("C:\Users\Kangkan\Desktop\ikea.png")
fil = p.make_statistical_outlier_filter()
fil.set_mean_k (50)
fil.set_std_dev_mul_thresh (1.0)
fil.filter().to_file("inliers.pcd")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ccordoba12 python-pcl`

This references wasn't available when you asked the question, but using it worked for me! https://anaconda.org/ccordoba12/python-pcl.

I am using windows and ran the conda install line with cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
conda install -c sirokujira python-pcl --channel conda-forge
```

Found solution on this website [https://anaconda.org/sirokujira/python-pcl] yesterday.
I am using Python 3.6 in Anaconda3 for Windows10(64).Hope this would be useful for you.

Comment: Note: This (obviously, in retrospect) only works if `pcl` itself is already installed. E.g. using `conda install -c sirokujira pcl --channel conda-forge`