# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pcl'

Tags: python

I'm running Spyder and Anaconda on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I've installed Point Cloud Library using:

```
conda install -c menpo/label/master pcl
```

when I have "import pcl" in my python scipt, I get and error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pcl'
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: can you find the module in the listing produced by `help(modules)` in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: PCL is not listed in help("modules") however is it visible in conda list

Comment: how about this duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437745/anaconda-and-point-cloud-library

Comment: This is what I've done already. Is there anyway to make the help("modules") and conda list match up?