# Not able to install Point Cloud Library onto python using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, point-cloud-library

Hi all I am having a hard time installing the PCL or point cloud library onto python using the function conda install -c conda-forge pcl. I am getting all types of errors and it is not installing pcl properly and there is something about a brew? Please help

I have tried many things and even looked at the Point Cloud Library website, but I can't seem to find anything

Answer (score 0):

You can try other channels instead too, sometimes it works, check here for other channels:
[pcl anaconda three channels](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pcl)
If that still doesnot work then try in anaconda powershell `pip install pcl`.

I hope this will help.

Comment: This answer also might be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437745/anaconda-and-point-cloud-library?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation of the python package](https://github.com/davidcaron/pclpy):

`conda install -c conda-forge -c davidcaron pclpy`

The package you installed (`pcl`) - it is just the binary dependencies. You need to install `pclpy`, which is the python wrapper.